# Keyboard brightness keys are not working after ubuntu installation, how to set the brightness?

Tags: keyboard, brightness

The brightness option is not showing in settings :

[brightness menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnrpv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1- click on system setting (from the drop list on the top right corner on next to the time).

2-click on brightness & lock.

3- change  the brightness ,like you want, form the brightness bar.

if you are using laptop.

1-you can click on the battery ( on the top right corner on next to the speakers control).

2-click on the power settings form the drop list.

3- in the new opened window you  will find tip.

4- click on screen brightness.

Comment: Hey thanks. But the brightness option in the brightness and lock menu is not showing actually.